# Hashicorp Vault - should you store customer-provided secrets in kv?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I need to store very sensitive secrets that a user provides me with (username+password+certificate for authenticating into a 3rd party API).

I was first considering AWS Secrets Manager, which is very expensive and IMHO mainly for infrastructure secrets (database passwords, API keys, ...) and not customer-provided secrets. Now I'm deciding between using AWS KMS (and storing the secrets encrypted in a database (AWS RDS) using envelope encryption) and Hashicorp Vault.

- https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/transit
- https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2

From what I've read, I've come to the conclusion, that Vault KV is mainly for infrastructure secrets and Vault Transit might be somewhat equivalent to AWS KMS (as in, better for customer-provided secrets).

Since I'm building a very small application, if I decide to use the Vault KV, I won't need a database at all. But I'm not sure if Vault KV is the right fit.

Is there some limitation or a possible problem (for this use-case) with Vault KV I should be aware of?

Thanks

Comment: The differences between encrypting with the Transit secret engine and the KV2 secret engine are for reasons other than the non-technical origin of the secrets themselves.

Comment: if you only need to store static data, dont go with vault. Use aws KMS/parameter store. Go for vault if you can utilise more functionality out of it

Comment: @user2599522 that is a good point!

Answer (score 1):

#### About KMS

AWS KMS is really only to manage the main master key. Parameter store will use KMS under the hood to manage its encryption keys. And if you deploy Vault in AWS, you’ll probably use KMS too to unseal and as the master key. You probably don’t want to use KMS directly (because the other solutions give you per secrets/path policies, secret versioning, audit logs, all features you probably want/need that KMS won’t give you directly)

#### Vault KV secrets engine versus Vault transit secrets engine

Vault key-value secrets engine let you store the secret, and Vault manages the encryption, audit logs, accesses (and versions if you use KV v2)

The transit secrets engine can be seen as "encryption as a service":

- you call it to create a keyring (think about it as a data encryption key, with rotation mechanisms built in, hence the keyring.)
- then you can it with a keyring reference to either encrypt some stuff, and get some encrypted cipher text back that you can store in a database, or in a file. Or you can do the reverse, and call it with a keyring reference, some cipher text, and ask it to decrypt this and get the data back (assuming you have the correct policies)
- or, if the data you want to encrypt/decrypt is "large" (depending on your use case), you can use it to get a data key you can use to locally encrypt/decrypt your data. (you get the key, encrypt or decrypt it, but you don’t have to deal with the encryption key security: Vault manages that for you, so you can just clean it from memory, and get it back from Vault the next time)

#### Should you use Vault or AWS SSM Parameter Store?

Like so many things: it depends. It depends on your criteria. I do love both, but for different use cases, so let me list the main differences I see between both, and hopefully, it will give you enough context to make your choice:

- Managed or not? :  AWS SSM Parameter Store is fully managed, and cheap, so this is a burden you don’t have to think about. If Parameter Store fills your needs, go with it, it gives you some precious time back to work on other things.
- Access management: Vault comes with a lot of authentication options, and easy to reason about policies. If IAM policies are enough to cover all your use cases to grant minimal access to these secrets, Parameter Store is a good option. Otherwise Vault will get you covered.
- Don’t forget Vault provides a lot of other secret/encryption tools. Chances are they can benefit your project (or not, but check this)

My rule of thumb would be: if AWS IAM is enough, and you don’t have any other needs than simple secret storage, SSM Parameter Store sounds like a good idea.
If you have other encryption needs, or some other authentication/policy requirements that would make it more challenging to build on top of IAM< Vault will shine.
And if you have a lot of secrets to store/encrypt/decrypt, Vault’s transit secret engine to encrypt/decrypt the data, and you regular DB to store these encrypted blob will work perfectly.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't even considering AWS SSM Parameter store (on purpose). It was either Vault or KMS+RDS (where the data would be stored in tables, but encrypted).

Answer (score 0):

Curious why your are avoiding AWS SSM. May be a little to limiting if you have a lot of data to encrypt and store but just curious.

It seems like if you want to avoid cost of Secrets Manager, than an encrypted RDS database isn't gaining you too much.

AWS Secrets Manager seem pretty reasonable unless you have a VERY high volume.